# Find all the persons which does not contain the provided resources

Tags: sql, postgresql

Below are the tables

```
CREATE TABLE Person(
    PersonID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    FirstName VARCHAR(10),
    LastName VARCHAR(10));

CREATE TABLE Resources(
    ResourceID CHAR(3) PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE PR (
    PersonID INT,
    ResourceID CHAR(3),
CONSTRAINT pkpr PRIMARY KEY (PersonID, ResourceID),
CONSTRAINT fkPersonID FOREIGN KEY (PersonID) REFERENCES Person(PersonID),
CONSTRAINT fkResourceID FOREIGN KEY (ResourceID) REFERENCES Resources(ResourceID));


INSERT INTO Person(PersonID, FirstName, LastName) VALUES (1, 'Bill', 'Smith'),(2, 'John','Jones'), (3, 'Tim', 'Jolt');
INSERT INTO Resources (ResourceID) VALUES ('ABC'),('DEF'),('HIJ');
INSERT INTO PR (PersonID, ResourceID) VALUES (1,'ABC'),(1,'DEF'),(2,'ABC'), (2,'HIJ'), (1,'HIJ'), (3, 'DEF');
```

How to find all the persons which does not have resources ('ABC', 'HIJ') ?

With above inserted data it should return person Tim Jolt

I am using PostgreSql.

Comment: Doesn't have any of the values, or doesn't have both of them?

Comment: A bit poor sample data, it should cover more possible combinations.

Comment: @jarlh Returned person should not have any of these values

Comment: JOIN. GROUP BY, HAVING. Or EXCEPT.

Answer (score 2):

So your main source of entity is the Person table. And you need to ignore all Persons which have the given resources.

So the SQL will be like below.

```
select PersonID from Person where PersonID not in ( select PersonID from PR where ResourceID in ('ABC', 'DEF'))
```

Comment: I want to achieve this without sub query

Comment: @akashdeepwadhwa, explain why you want it without a subquery.

Comment: @akashdeepwadhwa  `select person.* from person natural left join pr group by person.personid having count(*) filter (where resurceid in ('ABC', 'DEF')) = 0;` But why do you think that it will be faster?

Comment: @akashdeepwadhwa I don't think you can do it without a sub-query.

Comment: @NirAlfasi What about my query above?

Comment: @Abelisto I didn't test it but just from reading it LGTM!

Comment: @NirAlfasi this is very much possible without sub query.

Comment: @AkhileshMishra of course you can JOIN on a query instead of using it as a *sub*-query but it's practically the same...

Comment: it depends.For more clarity Please read [this](https://www.percona.com/blog/2020/04/16/sql-optimizations-in-postgresql-in-vs-exists-vs-any-all-vs-join/#:~:text=In%20general%2C%20EXISTS%20and%20direct,query%20is%20rewritten%2Ftransformed%20internally.)

Answer (score 2):

You can write your query in following 4 ways:

1. Using **NOT IN**: same answered by *Pratik Soni*

```
select personid from person 
where personid not in ( select personid from PR where resourceid in ('ABC', 'HIJ'))
```

2. Using **NOT EXIST**:

```
select personid from person t1 
where  not exists (select 1 from PR where personid=t1.personid and resourceid in ('ABC', 'HIJ'))
```

3. Using **<> ALL**:

```
SELECT personid FROM person WHERE
personid <> ALL(select personid from PR where resourceid in ('ABC', 'HIJ'))
```

4. Using **LEFT JOIN and IS NULL**

```
SELECT p.personid
FROM person p
LEFT JOIN PR r ON p.personid = r.personid AND r.resourceid in ('ABC', 'HIJ')
where r.personid is null
```

All 4 methods have their own pros and cons. No body can predict the performance without seeing `Explain Analyze` result. So check the execution plan using all above queries with real data and decide accordingly what method you should adopt.

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=cc2c59661219f296103c16fd214bbace)